# Changes in a test not pulling through to the app context

Tags: python, flask, pytest

I'm running a flask application and I wanted to set up some tests for it.

**conftest.py**:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def app():
    application.config['TESTING'] = True
    ctx = application.app_context()
    ctx.push()
    yield application


@pytest.fixture
def client(app):
    return app.test_client()


@pytest.mark.django_db
@pytest.fixture
def logged_in_client(app):
    with app.test_request_context():
        with app.test_client() as client:
            yield client


@pytest.fixture
def user():
    return User.query.first()
```

My test:

```py
def test_authenticated_access(app, logged_in_client, user):
    """
    GIVEN an attempt to access page
    WHEN a user is logged in
    THEN return a 200 code 
    """
    login_user(user)    
    print(current_user)
    res = logged_in_client.get("/project")
    assert res.status_code == 200
```

However, on running this test, the `current_user` is not being updated on the app.

Instead, the current user is being set to be a `flask_login.mixins.AnonymousUserMixin`, while if I try to print the `current_user` in the test script location it gives me the correct output.

Any way in which the changes made in my test script could let me change the value for `current_user` in the main app?

Comment: what does `login_user` do? Does that use the `logged_in_client` instance at all? Otherwise how does that know about the user?

Comment: @Oin login_user is a function that comes with the flask_login library and manages the current_user logged in for authentication purposes. You can pass it a User object to mark it as the logged in user. I assumed that since I'm using the same context for the test as the context of the app, I would be able to maintain the state change which login_user causes